# Finding kernel and range of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are given:

> Find $\ker(T)$, and $\textrm{rng}(T)$, where $T$ is the linear transformation given by
>
> $$T:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$$
>
> with standard matrix
>
> $$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
>     1 & -1 & 3\\
>     5 & 6 & -4\\
>     7 & 4 & 2\\
>     \end{array}\right]\textrm{.}
> $$

The kernel can be found in a $2 \times 2$ matrix as follows:

$$ L = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    a & b\\
    c & d\\
    \end{array}\right] = (a+d) + (b+c)t
$$

Then to find the kernel of $L$ we set

$$(a+d) + (b+c)t = 0$$
$$d = -a$$
$$c = -b$$

so that the kernel of $L$ is the set of all matrices of the form
$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    a & b\\
    -b & -a\\
    \end{array}\right]
$$

but I do not know how to apply that to this problem.

Comment: Kernels are defined for *linear transformations*, not matrices.  Usually when we say the "kernel of a matrix $A$", what we really mean is the kernel of the linear transformation $x \mapsto Ax$ for a column matrix $x$.  The kernel in that case will be a set of column matrices.  So I don't understand what you mean when you say that the kernel of $L$ is the set of matrices $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & -a\end{bmatrix}$.  Can you expand on what exactly you mean and where this comes from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & -1 & 3\\
    5 & 6 & -4\\
    7 & 4 & 2\\
    \end{array}\right]
$$
Consider a linear map represented as a $m × n$ matrix $A$ .
The kernel of this linear map is the set of solutions to the equation $Ax = 0$
$$
ker(A)=\{x \in R^n|Ax=0\}
$$
$$
det(A)=1(12+16)-(-1)(10+28)+3(20-42)=0
$$
Since $det(A)=0$ , $x\ne0$ and $0$ is a vector here. 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & -1 & 3\\
    5 & 6 & -4\\
    7 & 4 & 2\\
    \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{r}
   a\\b\\c
   \end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{r}
   0\\0\\0
   \end{array}\right]
$$
In row-reduced form,
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & 0 & \frac{14}{11}\\
    0 & 1 & \frac{-19}{11}\\
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{array}\right]
$$
$$x=\frac{-14}{11}z$$
$$y=\frac{19}{11}z$$
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
   a\\b\\c
   \end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{r}
   -14\\19\\11
   \end{array}\right]z
$$
Similarly for $2×2$ matrix .

Answer (score 2):

For range (T), just row reduce A to Echelon form, the remaining non-zero vectors are basis for Range space of T.

Answer (score -2):

To find the range(image) of T, find the transpose of the matrix first and then reduce the transposed matrix to an echelon form, the remaining non zero matrix becomes the basis for the range and the dimension becomes the rank

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: Giving a hurried and partial (you do not even mention the kernel of $T$) Answer after so much time has passed is of negligible value.  When an older Question already has an Accepted and/or upvoted Answer, it is expedient to carefully highlight what new information is being added (thus demonstrating that you've considered the existing Answers and are not simply repeating the work of others).